# Restart Apache after expiration of SSL

Tags: linux, apache, ssl

I use SSL for my domain.

When I restart Apache, I have to enter my pass phrase.

My SSL will expire in the near future and I am not going to extend.

After expiration, can I restart Apache correctly without entering pass phrase?

(After expiration, is there no need to change any settings of my server in order to restart Apache?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do nothing in your vhost config, apache will even after expiration serve the SSL cert to your users. This means that:

- on a restart you must still enter your passphrase
- your users get a big scary warning screen every time they try to view your site.

So make sure that you turn off SSL in your config before it expires (or just renew your cert)